# Bluemix Spark with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I have a Bluemix trial and I want to use it with a Java application that I have developed using Spark framework using swift storage. This application uses Maven for its build process.I know there is a Spark service in BlueMix.

I have several questions:

- Should I use Jave liberty and then bind Spark and Object storage to
  it?
- What is the the proper way to declare spark imports?
- What is the proper way to authorize against Object storage in my Java
  program as Softlayer doesn't support keystone?

Are there any examples that I can look at for deploying such app into Bluemix?

Comment: This question was [referenced on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311287/random-testing-posts-in-triage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bluemix Apache Spark Service currently, as of Nov 1st, 2015, only supports Jupyter notebooks, for scala and python language kernels. You cannot bind a java app to this notebook service.

Comment: http://www.cio.com/article/2997579/data-analytics/ibm-stirs-spark-as-a-service-into-ibm-bluemix.html and I can actually bind the spark service to Java liberty